# Are environment variables available to system-level startup scripts in WIndows?

Tags: windows, boot, script, environment-variables, group-policy

I'm planning on running a system startup script from Group Policy.  System startup scripts defined in the Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Scripts (Startup/Shutdown) node differ from logon scripts in that they run with the LocalSystem account's credentials and are processed before WinLogon runs (which allows a user to log onto the workstation).

I want the script to be located in %ProgramFiles%, which is an environment variable that usually (but not always) points to C:\Program Files.

Can I count on this variable being available, given that WinLogon has not yet run?

To be clear, this is where the script is being defined:

[image: System Startup Scripts]

Comment: So the actual question is: “Are environment variables expanded in this use case?” Because there’s no rule saying you can use environment variables *everywhere*.

Comment: @EMK; Thank you very much for the info. If you would like to post that as an answer instead of a comment I can accept it and give you the credit :-)

Comment: I've put in the answer and provided some formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see this in action you can capture a [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) boot trace ('Options' -> 'Enable boot logging').

To reduce events captured, you can:

- Add a filter for the operation 'Process Start';
- select 'Drop Filtered Events' from the 'Filter' menu to lighten the load.

After rebooting and saving the .PML. you can see from the 'Event' tab of a 'Process Start' event, the processes environment variables.

["By default, a child process inherits the environment variables of its parent process."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682653(v=vs.85).aspx)

You have the the following process tree ('Tools' - 'Process Tree') to launch your batch file:

```
|-->Wininit.exe
|---->services.exe
|------>svchost.exe  (C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe -k GPSvcGroup)
|-------->gpscript.exe
|---------->cmd.exe  (C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "C:\program files\script.bat")
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBPw3.jpg